# When using the onUpdate function in Firebase, how do I retrieve the record that has been updated?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

When using the cloud functions on firebase, with the onUpdate trigger, how do I retrieve the record that has been updated (in other words, the record that triggers the function)? I am using JavaScript to interface with the Firebase database.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first argument passed your [onUpdate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_.refbuilder#on-update) handler function is a [Change](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.change) object.  This object has two properties, `before` and `after`, both [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_.datasnapshot) objects.  These DataSnapshot objects describe the contents of the database before and after the change that triggered the function.

```
exports.foo = functions.database.ref('/location-of-interest')
.onUpdate((change) => {
    const before = change.before  // DataSnapshot before the change
    const after = change.after  // DataSnapshot after the change
})
```

Comment: thanks for this! So then can the constants 'before' and 'after' then be treated like a regular object? for example: console.log(before.bidAmount) (if bidAmount was a field of the record in the database)

Comment: Click through to the API documentation link I gave to DataSnapshot objects.  You can get the raw data out of the snapshot with the val() method.

Comment: anyone can provide updated links from the accepted answer? all links are broken (404) @DougStevenson

Answer (score 3):

per https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onUpdate

`onUpdate(handler) => function(functions.Change containing non-null functions.database.DataSnapshot, optional non-null functions.EventContext)`

So I'm guessing that you just need to pass a callback function into the `onUpdate(callback)` trigger. Per the documentation, the record of that has been updated would seem to be passed in as the first argument. I would start by logging the arguments object inside the callback function.

The example inside the docs is:

```
// Listens for new messages added to /messages/:pushId/original and creates an
// uppercase version of the message to /messages/:pushId/uppercase
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
      const original = snapshot.val();
      console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.pushId, original);
      const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
      // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
      // writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.
      // Setting an "uppercase" sibling in the Realtime Database returns a Promise.
      return snapshot.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
    });
```