# onUpdate function in firebase is not retrieving before state

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using `onUpdate` function to retrieve a `before` state, but `before` and `after` are returning the same value:

```
exports.subscriptionDowngradeHandler = async (change, context) => {
    const before = change.before.data().product;
    console.log("product before: ", before);
    const after = change.after.data().product;
    console.log("product after: ", after);

    await change.after.ref.set({
        before: before.id,
        after: after.id
    }, { merge: true });
}
```

Value `before.data().product` is expected to be the other id, but instead is the actual one as `after.data().product`

***EDIT***

index.js is just calling subscriptionDowngradeHandler as a handler for the function:

```
const authModule = require("./auth");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const creditsModule = require("./credits");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const subscriptionsModule = require("./subscriptions");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.subscriptionDowngrade =
  functions.firestore
    .document("/customers/{userId}/subscriptions/{pushId}")
    .onUpdate(subscriptionsModule.subscriptionDowngradeHandler);
    
exports.subspriptionPeriodEnd = functions.firestore
  .document("/customers/{userId}/subscriptions/{pushId}")
  .onWrite(subscriptionsModule.subscriptionPeriodEndHandler);
```

`subscriptions.js` is as follows:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

exports.subscriptionPeriodEndHandler = async (change, context) => {
    const periodEndBefore = change.before.data().current_period_end;
    const periodEndAfter = change.after.data().current_period_end;
    console.log(periodEndBefore);
    console.log(periodEndAfter);
   
}

exports.subscriptionDowngradeHandler = async (change, context) => {
    const before = change.before.data().product;
    const after = change.after.data().product;

    await change.after.ref.set({
        before: before.id,
        after: after.id
    }, { merge: true });
}
```

In both functions `before` and `after` shows exactly the same data.

Comment: Please edit your question to show how this code is invoked from within your index.js file.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for letting me know about the edit, it's already there!

Comment: try adding a confition to check whether or not before and after are the same

Comment: @Moukimhfaiedh I mean, if there's an update on the document I want to be able to see that update, more specifically, updates are going to change between one of three products, I want to see the last product (that's what I thought `before` does) so I can compare it with the actual one(`after`), if it's a "cheaper" product, some logic must be done, but both cases shows the same product id, as if it weren't changed, but product id indeed change inside firestore.

Comment: I think you could try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938753/when-using-the-onupdate-function-in-firebase-how-do-i-retrieve-the-record-that) to organize your code to isolate the handler